# Aparecer borda com hover CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de que quando eu passar o mouse por cima do item do menu mostrasse uma borda em cima e em baixo do item com a cor branca, mas não está funcionando.

Exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha aplicação

[Link para ir para aplicação com o problema](https://jsfiddle.net/v718rxtg/10/)

Comment: O link não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav navbar-nav .conteudo:hover{
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;    
}
```

nav e navbar-nav são classes de uma mesma tag, por isso o CSS não funciona, você deve utilizar uma única classe de cada tag para fazer a referência. Retire o navbar-nav e o código funcionará.

Forma correta:

```
 .nav .conteudo:hover{
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;    
}
```

Comment: nav .navbar-nav .conteudo:hover{ border-top: 3px solid white; border-bottom: 3px solid white; } Ta errado o seletor CSS